# Unity dll not found exception, но он есть. В чем проблема?

Tags: unity3d, dll

Я запускаю VMWare Win10, и там же установил Unity. Также на моем host PC (win10) у меня есть Unity, где я могу без проблем запускать свой проект Unity. Затем я заархивировал свой проект и через файлообменник переместил его на VM, где распаковал его и запустил с Unity.

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь запустить этот проект на VM, я получаю сообщение об ошибке `dll not found exception`, это странно, потому что, во-первых, на моем host PC этот проект работает без проблем, а во-вторых, я добавил все возможные dll-зависимости сюда `C:\buffer\coSample\coSample\Assets\coPlayer\Plugins`

[image]

Я решил проверить `dependency walker` могут ли там быть какие-то проблемы

[image]

но похоже там все ок.

Я так же проверил лог Unity. Но файл слишком длинный, поэтому я добавил его в GitHub gist

https://gist.github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/3edbcd4baeed7e162c715a91225e348b

Но там я увидел то же самое, что и в Unity editor log

```
...
DllNotFoundException: coDecoderEngine
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) coCAPI.register_debug_callback(coCAPI/DebugCallback)
  at coCAPI.register_debug_callback_default () [0x00000] in C:\buffer\coSample\coSample\Assets\coPlayer\Runtime\Scripts\coCAPI.cs:54 
  at coPlayer.StartStream (System.String pathToFile, System.Boolean noAudio) [0x00000] in C:\buffer\coSample\coSample\Assets\coPlayer\Runtime\Scripts\coPlayer.cs:302 
  at coPlayerGpu.StartStream (System.String pathToFile, System.Boolean noAudio) [0x00000] in C:\buffer\coSample\coSample\Assets\coPlayer\Runtime\Scripts\coPlayerGpu.cs:63 
  at coPlayer+<Start>d__77.MoveNext () [0x00051] in C:\buffer\coSample\coSample\Assets\coPlayer\Runtime\Scripts\coPlayer.cs:340 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00026] in <04258d1cdc1044248c2a17a6a31a3cf7>:0 
...
```

Но так и не понятно, почему юнити говорит, что не может найти этот dll когда он там (видно на скриншоте выше)

Так что вопрос - как понять в чем проблема? Что за dll который юнити ищет? Может ли это быть как то связано с тем, что я пробую запустить это на VMware?